# Autocomplete Combobox in Lightswitch with custom summary property

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, autocompletebox

I have three tables in SQL:

1. "tbProduct"

   ```
   ProductID | ProductName | ProductNumber
   ```
2. "trProductGroup"

   ```
   ProductGroupID | ProductID | ProductGroupID
   ```
3. "tbGroup"

   ```
   GroupID | GroupName
   ```

In Lightswitch I want to be able to assign a product to a product group. This is easy by creating a grid for tbGroup and creating a grid for trProductGroup where i can select products coming from tbProduct. Now I can enter the product number (summary property) in the grid representing trProductGroup. I can also **display** the product name inside the dropdown menu and in the grid...

But I want to be able to **select** the product by its name **and** number. So i want to have a column with a combobox showing the product name, where i can search for the prouct name, just a i can now for the product number. I think this could be achieved by changing the summary property for this particular column only. When I change the summary property in the object definition, entering the product number wouldn't work anymore.

Thanks for reading!

Edit: I created a small Video which shows my problem. You can see it here (Flash): https://dl.dropbox.com/u/161205/LightswitchTest/Lightswitch.AutocompleteComboBox.html

You may also download the project to have a look: 
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/161205/LightswitchTest/LightswitchTest.zip

Comment: Have you tried creating a custom Silverlight control to give you more capabilities for the ACB?

Comment: hi. well, i thought about it. but honestly, i have no clue how to implement the logic for this. it shure would be awesome to have a control where you can define any property as summary property.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the control type in the *ACB*, from a *Summary* control to a *ColumnsLayout* control. Then you can add whatever proprties that you want to display (one, or more than one, if you want).

Comment: Hi Yann, thanks for you advice. You are right, i can _diplay_ any property. But i want to use the _autocomplete_ combobox so i can search for another property than the summary property. If I change to ColumnsLayout the combobox still searches in the summary property, but displays the selected property. This is not what I want. I hope i was able to express myself clearly - if not please let me know, I will try to do better then.

Comment: What do you mean "the ACB still searches in the Summary property"? An ACB doesn't have any search capability, only a MWP (ModalWindowPicker).

Comment: I uploaded a small video, i hope this helps you to understand me.